# Finding the $n$-th derivative at $0$ rigorously (Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\displaystyle f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-1/x} , & x > 0 \\
0, &x \leq 0
\end{cases}$

Find (with justification) $f^{(n)} (0)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

(I am currently in the Differentiation chapter of Baby Rudin).

By L'Hôpital's Rule, it follows that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^n} = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. However, I am unsure on how to conclude that $f^{(n)} (0)=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You can use induction.

Comment: I don't follow the reference to L'Hospital. If you apply it to $\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^n}$, then you have a limit of $\frac{e^{-1/x}(1/x^2)}{nx^{n-1}}=\frac{e^{-1/x}}{nx^{n+1}}$. The power of $x$ in the denominator gets larger, so no matter how many times you iterate, you don't get down to a constant denominator.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show by induction $H(n): \forall x ≤ 0, f^{(n)}(x) = 0$ and $\forall x > 0, f^{(n)}(x) = P_n(\frac{1}{x})e^{-1/x}$ with $P_n$ a polynomial.

In the induction step, once you have proved $H(n)$ for $x>0$ and $x < 0$ 
You will have to show $f^{n+1}(x) = 0$: Write the definition of the slope at $0$ and look at the limits in $0^+$ and in $0^-$ applying these two results and limit comparison between $\exp$ and polynomial for $x >0$

Comment: Do you mean $H(n): \forall x ≥ 0, f^{(n)}(0) = 0$?

Comment: I have corrected. Thanks

Comment: I’m not sure how to write out the proof for $H(n)$, could you elaborate more on it? I would know how to proceed once the proof is established (after we prove $H(n), we can use Mean Value Theorem).

Comment: @Primes I have edited, is it more clear now? Actually the only problem is in $0$.